# Building and running a ARM Kernel with QEMU

Tags: command-line, linux-kernel, qemu, arm

I am trying to build a generic arm kernel and then run it with QEMU but not having any success.

I downloaded linux-4.17.13.tar.xz from Kernel.org extracted it and ran the commands below to build it

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi- alldefconfig
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi- nconfig
```

Enabled the following options:

```
[*] 8250/16550 and compatible serial support
[*] Console on 8250/16550 and compatible serial port
```

Finally running

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi- -j2 zImage
```

Then I ran the command to start qemu with the kernel image

```
qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -m 128M -kernel arch/arm/boot/zImage -nographic -append "console=ttyS0"
```

Here I see no output of any kind after presssing enter, just a newline and a hanging cursor on the terminal. 
What have I missed or am I doing wrong?

Comment: what would help make this question more specific?

Comment: Nobody? 5 users think its vague but none have recommendations on how to improve it. Interesting.

Comment: Have you made any progress on that? I am having the exact same problem as you did!

Comment: @perror no unfortunately I have not.